# Django: dynamically access queryset data from different models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-queryset

I'm interested in learning how to display all attributes of a list of querysets **that come from different models**.

Here's an example:

models.py

```
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    attr1 = something
    attr2 = something 

class MyModelB(models.Model):
    attr3 = something
    attr4 = something 

class MyModelC(models.Model):
    attr5 = something
    attr6 = something
```

views.py

Let's say we have three model instances that are stored in a list:

```
all_selected_queries = [mymodela, mymodelb, mymodelc]
```

For each queryset in the list, I want to display all model field titles and data in a template.

My approach:

```
# Loop through the list and get the verbose name title of each field ("titel")

for z in all_selected_queries:
    queryset_fields = z._meta.get_fields()
        for f in queryset_fields:
            titel = f.verbose_name.title()
            return titel
```

**What challenges me is how to get the fields' values without having to include the actual attribute name (because they are different for each queryset).**

So instead of explictly calling

```
f.attr1, f.attr2, f.attr3, f.attr4, f.attr5
```

for each field, I'd like to encounter a solution that works across model boundaries.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
v_list = list()
for z in all_selected_queries:
    queryset_fields = z._meta.get_fields()
    values = dict()
    for f in queryset_fields:
        values[f.verbose_name.title()] = getattr(z, f.attname)
    v_list.append(values)
return render(request,'some_template.html',{'values':v_list})
```

And show them in template:

```
{% for value in values %}
  {% for key, val in value.items %}
    <b>{{ key }}: </b>{{ val }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, @ruddra It works perfectly and I am very, very grateful that you saved me a lot of typing.